# Comparisons of arbitrary arithmetic types: does anyone know an implementation?

Tags: c++, comparison, c++11, numeric

While writing several math utilities I bumped into need to implement generic utility that can perform comparisons between any two fundamental arithmetic types. As I began coding, it became clear that this operation is not as straightforward as it seems, since I need correct handling of corner cases, especially when the types have different precision, i.e. rounding strategy during conversion between types becomes important. Consider:

```
float a1 = 4.8f;
int a2 = 4;
assert(a2 != (int) a1); //fails erroneously since we truncated a1

float b1 = 40000000.0f; //can represent only 40000000 and 40000004 accurately
long b2 = 40000002;
assert(b1 != (float) b2); //fails erroneously since we now truncated b2
```

The above can be implemented using c++0x type traits to automatically select the appropriate algorithm according to the template arguments supplied to the comparison function. However, this is quite complex and there's quite a lot of places where bugs can creep, so I don't think inventing everything myself is worthwhile. Does anyone know a library that implements the above correctly?

Comment: You're explicitly asking for truncation by casting. If you leave out the casts, the argument of "smaller" type is "promoted", nothing gets truncated and the assertions pass as expected. I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: You could always check if the float is an integer first using `modf`.

Comment: It's guaranteed that conversions of floating-point types to `long double`, signed integer types to `intmax_t` and unsigned integer types to `uintmax_t`, preserve the value. Is that sufficient for your purposes? (Edit: oops, probably not).

Comment: @delnan: Yes, both are promoted to double, yet the problem still holds: what to do when the value does not accurately fit in double?

Comment: @jons34yp: it's almost a moot point whether `40000000.0f` is equal to `40000002`, since in any practical circumstances, the integer value falls within the error range of the float value. You could convert both to a user-defined bigint type (from GMP or wherever), though, that will tell you whether or not they represent the same value. Alternatively, an 80-bit `long double` is enough to represent up to 64 bit integers exactly, so if your compiler will let you have one of those, it'll do as a common type. That's why x87 uses that size.

Comment: It's hard to get this right even for the integral types - eg comparing -1LL to a large positive unsigned long long. There is code in the implementation of boost numeric_cast that handles some of this, but I'm not sure if it's exposed as a general capability. It would be worth a look though.

Comment: I'm really curious to know how you came across this problem.

Comment: Here's a committee paper that touched on the issue for integral types, using min and max (and contains an implementation): http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2199.html

Comment: @SteveJessop: No, the floating point have no 'error range'. By the definition of IEEE754 standard, they are precise. It's the mathematical operations that are allowed to be imprecise.

Comment: @jons34yp: for the most accurate operations that aren't exact, the "error range" of the result is +/- 0.5 ulp. So if `40000000.0f` is the computed result, then "in any practical circumstances" 40000002 is in that range. That's what "error range" means, the range of exact results that would have produced the possibly-inaccurate result you came up with. I don't know what it is I said that you disagree with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into GNU's MP Bignum library at http://gmplib.org/.  From their page:

> GMP is a free library for arbitrary precision arithmetic, operating on
>   signed integers, rational numbers, and floating point numbers. There
>   is no practical limit to the precision except the ones implied by the
>   available memory in the machine GMP runs on. GMP has a rich set of
>   functions, and the functions have a regular interface.
>
> GMP is carefully designed to be as fast as possible, both for small
>   operands and for huge operands. The speed is achieved by using
>   fullwords as the basic arithmetic type, by using fast algorithms, with
>   highly optimised assembly code for the most common inner loops for a
>   lot of CPUs, and by a general emphasis on speed.